# $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1$. Prove that: $\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\ge \frac{a+b+c-6abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc}$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1$. Prove that:
> $$\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\ge \frac{a+b+c-6abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc}$$
> I posted it in [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3076901_sqrt_inequality).

Here is my attempt:

1. Approach 1:

It is easy by Schur inequality: $$a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\ge ab(a+b)+bc(c+b)+ca(c+a)=a+b+c-3abc$$
and: $a+b+c-3abc\ge a+b+c-6abc \iff abc\ge 0$. Also $a+b+c=(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\ge 9abc$.

Hence, we need to prove the following less ugly inequality:$$\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\ge \frac{a+b+c-6abc}{a+b+c-3abc}$$
After checking, the above inequality is wrong in case: $a=0.9; b=0.8$

2. Approach 2:

We can rewrite the original as pqr form: $$\sqrt{1-2pr}\ge \frac{p-6r}{p^3-3p+6r}$$
Squaring both side, we obtain: $$(1-2pr)(p^3-3p+6r)^2\ge (p-6r)^2$$
But it is quite complicated to me since the high degree yield $p^7; p^6,...$.

I continued toward with a powerful method which I have just known about it by some solutions recently. My following approach might be not good enough.

3. Approach 3:

I used uvw method, which set: $a+b+c=3u\ge \sqrt{3}; ab+bc+ca=3v^2=1;abc=w^3$. The original problem becomes: $$\sqrt{1-6uw^3}\ge \frac{3u-6w^3}{27u^3-9u+6w^3}$$

We can write it as a function of $w^3$: $$f(w^3)=\left(9u^3-3u+2w^3\right)\sqrt{1-6uw^3}+2w^3-u\ge 0$$
I do some calculating manipulation:

$$f^{'}(w^3)=2\sqrt{1-6uw^3}+\left(9u^3-3u+2w^3\right).\left(\sqrt{1-6uw^3}\right)^{'}+2$$
And: $\left(\sqrt{1-6uw^3}\right)^{'}=\dfrac{-3u}{\sqrt{1-6uw^3}}$
which implies:$$f^{'}(w^3)=2\sqrt{1-6uw^3}-\dfrac{3u(9u^3-3u+2w^3)}{\sqrt{1-6uw^3}}+2$$
I want to show that $f(w^3)$ is concave. Unluckily, I get some troubles.

It is:$f^{'}(w^3)$ can be positive sign in some cases. Here is an example:

$$f^{'}(w^3)=2\sqrt{1-6uw^3}-\dfrac{3u(9u^3-3u+2w^3)}{\sqrt{1-6uw^3}}+2<0$$
in case: $ a=0;b=\frac{\sqrt{238}}{7};c=\frac{\sqrt{238}}{34}$

But:
$$f^{'}(w^3)=2\sqrt{1-6uw^3}-\dfrac{3u(9u^3-3u+2w^3)}{\sqrt{1-6uw^3}}+2>0 $$
in case: $a=\frac{4}{5};b=\frac{9}{10};c=\frac{14}{85}$

It is quite interesting now. I don't give up so I came up with the idea that we can divide the starting problem into 2 cases.

Firstly, we will homogenize the derivative as: $$f^{'}(w^3)=2\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}-\dfrac{3u(9u^3-9uv^2+2w^3)}{\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}}+6v^2$$

If $f^{'}(w^3)<0$, it is equivalent to:$$9\left(3u^4-2v^4+2uw^3-3u^2v^2\right)=3u(9u^3-9uv^2+2w^3)-2\left(9v^4-6uw^3\right)>6v^2\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}$$
Or:$$ \sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}< \frac{3\left(3u^4-2v^4+2uw^3-3u^2v^2\right)}{2v^2}$$
In this case, $f(w^3)$ is concave. Hence, we just need to check:

- One variable is equal to $0$, assume: $a=0; bc=1$. We will show that:$b^3+c^3\ge b+c \iff (b+c)(b-c)^2\ge 0$
- Two of varibles are equal, assume: $0\le b=c=x\le 1;a=\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}$, which means we need to prove: $$\sqrt{x^4+2x^2\left(\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}\right)^2}\ge \frac{2x+\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}-6x^2.\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}}{2x^3+\left(\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}\right)^3+3x^2.\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}}$$
  I still stuck in proving by hand. I used [Checking software](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sqrt%5BPower%5Bx%2C4%5D%2BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2840%292Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%2BDivide%5B3x-3Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-%5C%2840%292x%2BDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D-3x%2B3Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29%3D0).

Now, it is enough to prove the OP true in case:$$ \sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}\ge \frac{3\left(3u^4-2v^4+2uw^3-3u^2v^2\right)}{2v^2}$$
It means we will prove the following inequality to end proof:
$$\frac{3\left(3u^4-2v^4+2uw^3-3u^2v^2\right)}{2v^2}\ge \frac{(3uv^2-2w^3)v^2}{9u^3-9uv^2+2w^3}$$
I guess today isn't my lucky day because the last inequality is wrong in case: $ a=\frac{4}{5};b=\frac{9}{10};c=\frac{14}{85}$.

> Some thoughts: I think the OP is not very hard but I still stuck to find a completed proof. For instance, BW and SOS work with deg 10 but I haven't tried.In any case, I will try my best to solve it. If anyone can continue with my idea (pqr approach) or find more possible ideas, please share it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

Firstly, we consider the case $abc=0.$

Plugging $a=0;bc=1$ the original inequality becomes $$bc\ge \frac{b+c}{b^3+c^3} \iff b^2+c^2\ge 2.$$

From now, we use $abc>0.$

By $ab+bc+ca=1$, we'll prove
$$\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\ge \frac{ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)-3abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc}.(ab+bc+ca),$$
or $$\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}+ab+bc+ca\ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)}{a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc}.(ab+bc+ca).$$

Now, we can eliminate the yield $a+b+c$ by multiplying $ab+bc+ca-\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}>0$ for both side.

Hence, it remains to prove
$$2abc\left(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\right)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)\left(ab+bc+ca-\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\right). \tag{1}$$

---

Notice that,\begin{align*}
&(ab+bc+ca)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2abc\left(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\right)\\&=\sum_{cyc}\left(2a^2bc(b^2+c^2)+b^2c^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)\right),
\end{align*}
then we can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\ge \sum_{cyc}\left(2a^2bc(b^2+c^2)+b^2c^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)\right).$$
From now, Cauchy-Schwarz helps well.

Indeed, it's sufficient to show that$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}.bc\ge 2a^2bc(b^2+c^2)+b^2c^2(b^2+c^2-a^2),$$
or
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\ge 2a^2(b^2+c^2)+bc(b^2+c^2-a^2).$$
Since
$a^2+b^2+c^2=\sqrt{(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2+4a^2(b^2+c^2)},$ we apply CBS inequality
as$$\sqrt{\left[(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2+4a^2(b^2+c^2)\right]\left[(bc)^2+a^2(b^2+c^2)\right]}\ge bc(b^2+c^2-a^2)+2a^2(b^2+c^2).$$

Thus, the proof is done. Equality holds at $(a,b,c)=(0,1,1).$

Comment: Nice. minor: When $abc = 0$, you multiply $ab+bc+ca-\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2} = 0$, do you need to add something like "if $abc = 0$, clearly it is true. Assume $abc > 0$"?

Comment: Thank you! I'll fix soon

Comment: @TATAbox How do you full the proof?

Comment: @RiverLi I added something. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @TATAbox It is a tricky use of CBS.

Answer (score 3):

In the standard $uvw$'s notation we need to prove that:
$$\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}\geq\frac{(9uv^2-6w^3)3v^2}{27u^3-27uv^2+6w^3}$$ or $f(u)\geq0,$ where
$$f(u)=(9u^3-9uv^2+2w^3)\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}-3(3uv^2-2w^3)v^2.$$
Now, $$f'(u)=(27u^2-9v^2)\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}-\frac{3w^3(9u^3-9uv^2+2w^3)}{\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}}-9v^4=$$
$$=3\left(\frac{81u^2v^4-27v^6-63u^3w^3+27uv^2w^3-2w^6}{\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}}-3v^4\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3(81u^2v^4-27v^6-63u^3w^3+27uv^2w^3-2w^6-3v^2\cdot3v^4)}{\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3(81u^2v^4-36v^6-63u^3w^3+18uv^2w^3)}{\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}}=\frac{27(9u^2v^4-4v^6-7u^3w^3+2uv^2w^3)}{\sqrt{9v^4-6uw^3}}\geq0$$ because we'll prove now that $$9u^2v^4-4v^6-7u^3w^3+2uv^2w^3\geq0.$$
Indeed, this inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$, which by $uvw$ says that it's enough to prove it in two following cases.

1. $w^3=0.$ In this case it's obvious.
2. Two variables are equal.

Since this inequality is homogeneous and for $b=c=0$ it's obviously true, we can assume $b=c=1$, which gives $$(a-1)^2(5a^2+8a+8)\geq0.$$
Id est, $f$ increases and by $uvw$ again it's enough to prove the starting inequality for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$. Thus, $c=\frac{1-a^2}{2a},$ where $0<a\leq1$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sqrt{a^4+2a^2\left(\frac{1-a^2}{2a}\right)^2}\geq\frac{2a+\frac{1-a^2}{2a}-6a^2\cdot\frac{1-a^2}{2a}}{2a^3+\left(\frac{1-a^2}{2a}\right)^3+3a^2\cdot\frac{1-a^2}{2a}}$$  or
$$(x-1)^2(3x+1)(9x^5+99x^4-72x^3+36x^2-9x+1)\geq0,$$ where $x=a^2$, which is true because
$$9x^5+99x^4-72x^3+36x^2-9x+1\geq99x^4-72x^3+15x^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Oops, nice solution. It is very hard for me to work properly because I am newbie in uvw method. What documents do I need to read more about this nice method ? I am very appreciate!

Comment: There is my paper in Russian. Do you want?

Comment: Thank you. Please sent it to me in private message AOPS.

Comment: In evening, OK? I am very busy now

Comment: Of course. In anytime is available for you, I'm very appreciate!

Comment: Dear @Michael Rozenberg, I think I found a very nice idea using C-S!

Answer (score 1):

Now, I found a SOS identity after homogenzing the original problem.
$$(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc)^2$$$$-(ab+bc+ca)^2(ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)-3abc)^2=$$
$$\left( \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{a} \right) \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\left[ \left( a^5b^2+a^5c^2+\frac{a^3b^4}{2}+\frac{a^3c^4}{2} \right) (b+c-a)^2+(b-c)^2\left( \frac{a^4b}{2}+\frac{a^4c}{2}+\frac{1}{2}a^3bc+\frac{3}{2}ab^2c^2 \right) (b+c-a)^2 \right]}\ge 0$$

Comment: It can not be true because RHS is cyclic and LHS is symmetric

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. I am trying fix it

Comment: Now, is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*: In your approach 2 (the pqr method), we can use the concave function rather than squaring both sides.

**Proof.**

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$.

From $q^2 \ge 3pr$, we have $r \le \frac{1}{3p}$.
From degree four Schur inequality, we have
$r \ge \frac{5p^2q - p^4 - 4q^2}{6p} = \frac{5p^2 - p^4 - 4}{6p}$. Thus, we have
$$\max\left(0, \frac{5p^2 - p^4 - 4}{6p}\right) \le r \le \frac{1}{3p}.$$

We need to prove that
$$f(r) := \sqrt{1-2pr} - \frac{p-6r}{p^3-3p+6r} \ge 0.$$
It is easy to prove that $f(r)$ is concave.

If $p \ge 2$, we have
$f(0) = \frac{p^2 - 4}{p^2 - 3} \ge 0$
and $f(\frac{1}{3p}) > 0$.
Thus, $f(r) \ge 0$ on $[0, \frac{1}{3p}]$.

If $\sqrt 3 \le p < 2$,
we have
$f(\frac{5p^2 - p^4 - 4}{6p}) \ge 0 $
and $f(\frac{1}{3p}) > 0$.
Thus, $f(r) \ge 0$ on $[\frac{5p^2 - p^4 - 4}{6p}, \frac{1}{3p}]$.

We are done.

Comment: Very nice approach! +1.